# how to handle html button in webView (cocoa)

Tags: html, macos, cocoa, webview

How can I handle the pressing of a HTML button in a WebView, the button would look like:

```
<input type="submit" name="mybutton" id="mybuttonid" value="test" />
```

The WebView is part of a Mac desktop application.

Comment: what do you mean by handle? do you want to click the button, or get the on-click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you mean by handle the button, but your solution will probably involve using 'stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString'.

For example:

```
[yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('mybuttonid')"];
```

Hope this helps :)